# Proving $\langle x\rangle \cap \langle y\rangle \space \subseteq \space \langle xy \rangle$ using that $\langle y \rangle$ is a prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I am trying to solve that, given the ring of polynomials $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, $\langle x\rangle \cap \langle y\rangle  \space  = \space \langle xy \rangle $. I have no problem showing that $\langle xy\rangle   \space \subseteq \space \langle x\rangle \cap \langle y \rangle $

My doubts arises with the other part, proving that : $\langle x\rangle \cap \langle y\rangle  \space \subseteq \space \langle xy \rangle $

My idea goes like this, I want you to comment if my resolution is right :  I start with a polynomial $p (x,y)$ that is in the intersection between $\langle x \rangle$ and $\langle y\rangle$. Therefore I can say that $p(x,y) = x q(x,y)$. Since $p(x,y)$ is also in $\langle y \rangle$ by hypothesis, and $\langle y \rangle $ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ (This is my crucial doubt and the reason for the title : Is this last affirmation correct ?)  , I deduce by definition of prime ideal that $q(x,y$) is in $\langle y\rangle$ (because $x$ is not). Then , if $q(x,y) = yh(x,y)$ I can say that $p(x,y) = xyh(x,y)$ and this is in $\langle xy \rangle$.

I would appreciate some comments (and corrections if its necessary) of my resolution.

Thanks you.

EDIT : A comment has proposed that since the homomorphism $F : \mathbb{C}[x,y] \to \mathbb{C}[x]$ has a kernel $\langle y \rangle$ therefore $\langle y \rangle$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

So basically I define the homomorphism $F(p(x,y)) = p(x,0)$ and then the kernel of F is $p(x,y) \in \langle y \rangle$  because otherwise $p(x,0) =/= 0$ . How can I conclude that kerF = $\langle y \rangle$ is a prime ideal of  $C[x,y]$ ?

Comment: Yes, $\langle y\rangle$ is the kernel of $C[x,y]\to C[x]$, hence prime

Comment: Say $p\in\langle x\rangle \cap \langle y\rangle$. Then $p=xq$ for some $q$, and $p=yt$ for some $t$. Then $y|xq$, and since $y$ is a prime element $y|x$ or $y|q$. Since $y$ does not divide $x$, then $y|q$. So $q=yv$ for some $v$, and $p=xq=xyv$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Hello, I did an edit in the original post. Have I interpreted you correctly? How could I deduce that KerF is a prime ideal of C[x,y] ? Thanks

Comment: The image is an integral domain, so the kernel is a prime ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your argument is correct. As Arturo has mentioned in the comments, a useful characterization of an ideal being prime is the following:

Assume $A$ is a commutative unital ring. An ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq A$ is prime if and only $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is an integral domain.

It is pretty easy to see that $\Bbb{C}[X]$ is an integral domain (indeed, the  product of nonzero polynomials is nonzero).

Comment: So, to put in a more formal way : If R is a conmutative ring with unity and I is an ideal of R, I is a prime ideal iff R/I is an integral domain. C[x] is also an integral domain. I know that C[x] is isomorphic to C[x,y]/<y> (because  First Theorem Isomorphism and F surjective). C[x,y]/<y>  Isomorphic to an integral domain therefore C[x,y]/<y> is integral domain.  Then <y> prime ideal. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.